# How can I make RedisOperations<String, List<Subscription>> instead of <K, V>?

Tags: java, lambda, redis

I'm trying to prevent race conditions in Redis by employing pessimistic lock.

Here what I did so far:

```
@Override
public void put(final Subscription subscription) {
    final String username = subscription.getUsername();
    redisTemplate.execute(new SessionCallback<List<Subscription>>() {
        @Override 
        public <K, V> List<Subscription> execute(RedisOperations<K, V> ops) { 
            ops.multi();
            ops.watch((K) SUBSCRIPTION);
            final List<Subscription> list = (List<Subscription>) ops.opsForHash().get((K) SUBSCRIPTION, username);
            final List<Subscription> updated = orEmpty(list);
            updated.removeIf(s -> s.getId().equals(generateId(username, subscription.getTargetUsername())));
            updated.add(subscription);
            ops.opsForHash().put((K) SUBSCRIPTION,  username, updated);
            ops.exec();
            return updated;
        }
    }); 
}
```

This piece of code looks terrible and contains a lot of warnings.

I would like to rewrite it in a lambda or at least generify it.

How can I make RedisOperations> instead of ?

Comment: If it works correctly, then Code Review is typically a better SE.

Comment: i think you cannot write lambda expression for `SessionCallback` because `execute` method has generic parameters

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.

Comment: I changed my question